# How to find the specific word from a comma separated column of varchar?

Tags: sql-server

I have a varchar type column in SQL Server that stores a comma separated value:

> gaurav,gupta,stackoverflow

I want to fetch the records where column has value `gupta`.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You should restructure this into first normal form. Otherwise you end up needing the inefficient `WHERE ',' + col1 + '', LIKE '%,gupta,%'`

Comment: @MartinSmith please put your comment as answer .. i think it is much better solution then the solutions given in answer part

Comment: Voted to close as dupe instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @strKeys varchar(100) ='gaurav,gupta,stackoverflow'

declare @strSearchValue varchar(30) = ',gupta,'
if(CHARINDEX(@strSearchValue,@strKeys) <> 0)
BEGIN
    select 'Found'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    select 'Not found'
END
```

Comment: there are so many wrong thing in answer 1) OP wants to in query 2) i think @strSearchValue  should be ',gupta,' instead of 'gupta' .. but this might be way for so i am not down vote this